# representability of some mapping stack

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, stacks, hilbert-schemes

Let $S$ be an Artin stack of finite type.
We assume that it contains a point as an open dense.

Is it always true that the mapping stack:

$Hom^{0}(\mathbb{P}^{1},S)$

which consists of sections generically in the pt, is a scheme?

It works for $[\mathbb{A}^{1}/\mathbb{G}_{m}]$ or $[M_{n}/GL_{n}]$, both acting on the left.